# How to test request's HTTP method in WebFilter?

Tags: java, servlets, filter

I have a *WebFilter* that acts as a filter for all JSP pages:

`"*.jsp"`.

How can I test if the request is a GET or POST to the JSP filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a check in your filter like this:

```
       HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;        
       if(httpRequest.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")){
           System.out.println("This is a POST request");
       } else if (httpRequest.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("GET")) {
           System.out.println("This is a GET request");
       }
```